# ReactJS ES6 adding logic to the component

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs, jsx

I have a chat feature and I'm trying to display an array of messages into my JSX code with a conditionally rendered className depending on a value in an object.

I'm really new to ES6 and React and I cannot figure how to go about this logic inside the JSX. I am using redux to map my state into props. For brevity, I've cut the code into its simplest form.

```
class ChatWidget extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={chat.body}>
        {/* if from_id == 1 */}
        <div className={chat.float-right}>
            <p>  {/* message of from_id==1 */} </p>            
        </div>
        {/* else */}
        <div className={chat.float-left}>
            <p> {/* else message here */} </p>               
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    messages: state.messages
  };
}
```

Here is my sample JSON array.

```
[
        {   
            msg_id: 1,
            to_id: 1,
            from_id: 2,
            message_id: "Marzipan jelly-o croissanty"
        },
        {   
            msg_id: 2,
            to_id: 2,
            from_id: 1,
            message_id: "Jelly sw"
        }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain your logic? You want to render message_id text from the object where from_id is 1 first, followed by other chat messages in what order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your messages array to create an array of JSX elements which can be used in another JSX expression for rendering.

Since you want the message with `from_id == 1` to appear first you can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to order the messages array 
(*to avoid mutating `messages` a shallow copy of the array is made using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)*).

You then then call [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the newly returned array to iterate through the sorted messages creating new JSX on each iteration.

The code could look something like this:

```
class ChatWidget extends Component {

  render() {
    // deconstruct messages from props
    const {messages} = this.props;

    // Mutating data should be avoided and Array#sort mutates 
    // the array so we use Array#slice to create a 
    // shallow copy before we sort it
    const msgCopy = messages.slice();

    // sort messages so message where from_id === 1 is first
    const sorted = msgCopy.sort((a,b) => {
      return a.from_id - b.from_id;
    });

    // iterate through sorted array to create 
    // an array JSX elements
    sorted.map(message => {
      const {from_id, message_id} = message;

      // Change class if from_id is 1
      const classToAdd = (from_id === 1) ? ('chat.convo + ' ' + chat.them'):('chat.convo');

      return (
        <div className={classToAdd}>
          <div className={chat.text}>
            <p>  { message_id } </p>            
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    // use sorted array as follows to create a div containing
    // a child div for each message
    return
    (
      <div className={chat.body}>
        {sorted}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    messages: state.messages
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it was not intended for the from_id to === 1 to be sorted first instead it should sorted by message_id

Comment: You have solved the sorting part but the logic in the component does not meet my business requirment

Comment: No problem. To sort on message_id amend the `.sort` callback return the following instead: `return a.message_id - b.message_id;`

Comment: Your question asks for a way to show a list of messages from an array in JSX. My answer provides one approach. Care to elaborate about what your​ business requirement is?

Comment: How do I add the logic of displaying them in the body, I have a css-class that makes it float right if it's from_id === 1 and otherwise if else. If you visualize a simple chat, that's how it should work, i already made a pseudo code in my example i just need the syntax to incorporate it into my JSX

Comment: I have simplified the html for brevity

Comment: I've amended my answer to include a ternary expression that decides what class to add.

Comment: Thanks! this is elegant

Comment: Cool beans. If you found my useful and/or it provided a solution for your question, please consider up-voting it and/or accepting it as the answer. This would be greatly appreciated.